# Connecting to Proxysql from PHP what credentials and port to be use

Tags: proxysql

I am creating an application which connects to the proxysql. All the clusters are configured through the proxysql but what credentials and port should I use in my application to connect to the proxysql?

Comment: HI, All I have used the same username and credentials that I have added in database and i am connecting on 6033 port. It's working for me.

Comment: When I try to connect with MySQL details it's connected but how i change proxysql query rules from PHP?

Answer (score 0):

All I have used the same username and credentials that I have added in database and i am connecting on 6033 port. It's working for me.